# how to find outgoing number in Telephony manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, calllog, telephonymanager

I am using this:

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
```

which is listening to:

```
telephonyManager.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

I want to know both outgoing and incoming calls but for now I only get incoming calls (when state changes is ringing). Can anyone tell me when can I detect outgoing call and its end

Also is there a way to simulate outgoing calls in Eclipse emulator. was able to do that for incoming calls via emulator control in eclipse.

Answer (score 13):

Use a broadcast listener with an intent `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` string parametrer for the `IntentFilter` and don't forget to give permission in AndroidMenifest to `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`. This will work. Whenever there is an outgoing call a toast message will be shown. Code is below.

```
public static final String outgoing = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" ;
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(outgoing);
BroadcastReceiver OutGoingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String outgoingno = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "outgoingnum =" + outgoingno,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
registerReceiver(brForOutgoingCall, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class, let say **MyPhoneReceiver**, extends it from BroadcastReceiver, and implement onReceive method.

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

    }
}
```

In another class, let say, **MainActivity.class** inside onCreate method. for example.

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    MyPhoneReceiver myPhoneReceiver = new MyPhoneReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myPhoneReceiver,filter);
```

In the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver
   android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and also in the AndroidManifest.xml, add:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS">
</uses-permission>
```